# Create one method for both opening and saving files in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

i tried to create a method for both opening and saving files because the code for both of them are really similar. Wanted to make it a bit cleaner but can't get it working. Here i'm at the moment.

I guess FileDialog is okay, but i don't know what to do with SaveFile and LoadFile.

Here is the code:

```
        // Open files
    private void atvērtFailuToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenSave(openFileDialog1, LoadFile);
    }

    // Save files
    private void saglabātFailuToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenSave(saveFileDialog1, SaveFile)
    }

    // Method for both opening and saving files.
    private void OpenSave(FileDialog dialog, RichTextBoxStreamType OpenLoad)
    {
        dialog.Filter = "RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
        dialog.AddExtension = true;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rtf_NotePad.OpenLoad(dialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED - IS IT RIGHT LEAVING AS IT IS?**

```
    private void atvērtFailuToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
        openFileDialog1.AddExtension = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rtf_NotePad.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        }
    }

    private void saglabātFailuToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
        saveFileDialog1.AddExtension = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rtf_NotePad.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use 2 methods and use Separate `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: Why do you want to merge open and save in a single method?

Comment: I thought i can create a simplier and shorter code that way.

Comment: I think this way, it would be harder to read and maintain :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei i updated my question. so should i leave as it is right now?

Comment: **You are having trouble optimizing save/open together b/c open and save are meant to be separated.** You could create one method by doing something like this `void save(boolean isSaving)`, with the boolean triggering whether it saves or loads, but there really is no concrete benefit to doing that and thus would "... be harder to read and maintain" (Reza) due to it being squashed together. Alternatively you could create your own open/save dialog but either solution would not be worth the development time investment.

Comment: A method which can do 2 different things and needs a flag or code or mode param to tell it which code to run is conceptually flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Open` and `Save` are 2 completely different operations and while technically you can mix them in a single method using a bool / enum value, but it makes your code harder to read and maintain.

If you look for a way to keep your hand writing codes to less lines:

- You can configure your `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` using designer and
- Then if you want to load and save only rtf files (as your code does it now), you can use [`SaveFile(path)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e(v=vs.110).aspx), [`LoadFile(path)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads.

Open:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    rtf_NotePad.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName)
```

Save:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    rtf_NotePad.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
```